# Retrofit 2 @FieldMap always empty

Tags: android, http, request, retrofit

I've made Map manually

```
private Map<String, Object> getProducts(){
    List<CartContentDMC> products = new Select().from(Data.class).execute();
    Map<String, Object> productMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    for(int j = 0; j < products.size(); j++){
        productMap.put("products[" + Integer.toString(j) + "][code]", Integer.toString(products.get(j).id));
        productMap.put("products[" + Integer.toString(j) + "][amount]", products.get(j).amount);
        productMap.put("products[" + Integer.toString(j) + "][price]", Integer.toString(products.get(j).price));
    }
    return productMap;
}
```

, but in my request:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("orders.json/createOrder?")
Call<Response> sendOrder(@Query("client_id") String id, @Query("access_token") String access_token,
                     @Query("order_id") int order_id, @Query("buyer_name") String buyer_name,
                     @Query("buyer_phone") String buyer_phone, @Query("buyer_address") String buyer_address,
                     @FieldMap Map<String, Object> products, @Query("delivery_price") int delivery_price,
                     @Query("website") String website);
```

FieldMap always empty in requests.

What I'm doin' wrong?

Comment: are you sure  that `products`  is filled up correctly?

Comment: @Blackbelt Absolutely! It give such map:
products[0][code],9
products[0][amount],3
products[0][price],15000
products[1][code],65
products[1][amount],5
products[1][price],15000
products[2][code],68
products[2][amount],2
products[2][price],25000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In such case better to use @QueryMap instead of @FieldMap.

Comment: `@QueryMap` and `@FieldMap` are two different things. `@QueryMap` adds the query to your url. `@FieldMap` fills up the body of your request